# How to center my HTML5 embeded video from youtube?

Tags: html, responsive-design, html5-video

I embedded a video link from YouTube to put into my website to use for school, when I pasted it and refreshed the video was aligned to the side.
I tried debugging it and tried  and a couple different ones but none worked. I reaserched and found nothing that fixed ( searched for 30 mins )
can anyone offer help? Or is it because I have a responsive design?

```html
<iframe class="right" width="1000" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V_qlumZ5K4I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></object>
```

This is Just My website BELOW

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Road to a healthier lifestyle
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
      <h1>
        <a href="index.html">Healthy living</a>
      </h1><a href="#nav">Menu</a>
    </header><!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul class="links">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" type="square">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="generic.html" type="square">Diabetes & obesity</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="elements.html" type="square">Ways to play less video games</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav><!-- Main -->
    <section class="wrapper" id="main">
      <div class="container">
        <header class="major special">
          <h2>
            Road to a healthier lifestyle
          </h2>
          <p>
            Ways to play less video games
          </p>
          <a><div class="seperate"></div></a>
          <object>
            <iframe align="center" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height=
            "500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y5RSngCFpsc" width=
            "1000"></iframe>
          </object>
        </header>
        <ul>
          <li>I. Think of why you wanted to stop gaming? Make reasons why you
          want to stop. This will help you understand.
          </li>
          <li>II. Make a note of how long you play every day. Then cut off an
          hour every day. This sort of progressive reduction will help your
          body adjust to the change, and doesn’t feel like your removing an
          important part of your daily life.
          </li>
          <li>III. Think of all the reasons you want to quit gaming for. What
          are the alternative things you could be doing? This might be
          improving your studying, learning a new hobby, seeing friends more
          often, spending more time with your family and/or pets, going out
          more, taking up a sport, etc.
          </li>
          <li>IV. When stopping something you love, it will hurt. You should be
          strict all the same, as cutting down requires removing the desire to
          play. Play for only a couple of hours on weekends, after you've
          finished your chores and the other things you want to do.
          </li>
          <li>V. Tell your parents to remind you to turn it off at a particular
          time. Make sure you turn it off at the designated time. No matter
          what checkpoint you need to reach, even if it's online or if it gets
          you banned.
          </li>
          <li>VI. If asking your parents doesn't work, download this simple
          software that will force your computer to shut down at a designated
          time:
          http://www.konradp.com/products/auto_shutdown/download/autoshutdown.exe
          </li>
          <li>VII. Set the time with the Force shutdown option to 2 hours
          lesser that what you did on your previous day. As the computer shuts
          off, unplug the mouse and keyboard.
          </li>
          <li>VIII. If you are a hardcore gamer who is active on the
          forums/public chat, then make a thread about you quitting - make it
          public. This will make your resolve stronger.
          </li>
          <li>IX. Try asking someone to hide your games from you for a few
          hours and gradually go up to a few days, weeks, months etc.
          </li>
          <li>X. Try doing other things to get your mind off gaming. Some
          examples are reading, sports, helping around the house, etc.
          </li>
          <li>XI. Never try to sneak onto video games, as this will make you
          want to play more and more and more. You will inevitably be
          discovered.
          </li>
          <li>XII. Don't try to prolong your gaming time. Things you should
          avoid include "May I please play 5 more minutes", "I need to finish
          this up or it won't save", and "I'm in the middle of something".
          Video games are no longer the highlight of the day. You have better
          things you would rather do, like reading, a sport, or another
          activity that is healthy for your mind and body.
          </li>
          <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <p>
              Tips
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>o •You don't have to give them up completely. Just strictly limit
          how long you play
          </li>
          <li>o •Whenever you feel that urge to play, resist it by occupying
          your hands with something else.
          </li>
          <li>o •Try to study harder and keep a timetable.
          </li>
          <li>o •Avoid anything to do with gaming, even something as simple as
          searching the internet for gaming reviews or forums.
          </li>
          <li>o •Get a knack for the more rewarding real life game. Read and
          practice.
          </li>
          <li>o •Organize your stuff.
          </li>
          <li>o •Understand that you can survive without video games.
          </li>
          <li>o •Drink water and rest your eyes often.
          </li>
          <li>o •Workout and exercise, eat fruits and stay healthy.
          </li>
          <li>o •Know your limits and don't try do so much in short time.
          </li>
          <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <div class="seperate"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section><iframe allowfullscreen="" class="right" frameborder="0" height=
    "500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V_qlumZ5K4I" width=
    "1000"></iframe> <!-- Footer -->
    <footer id="footer">
      <div class="inner">
        <ul class="icons">
          <li>
            <a class="icon fa-facebook" href="#"><span class=
            "label">Facebook</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="icon fa-twitter" href="#"><span class=
            "label">Twitter</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="icon fa-instagram" href="#"><span class=
            "label">Instagram</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="icon fa-linkedin" href="#"><span class=
            "label">LinkedIn</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="copyright">
          <li>&copy; By Ahmad abu shawar 9y
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer><!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="assets/js/util.js">
    </script> 
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
     
    <script src="assets/js/main.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thx lots guy, I managed to fix it

Comment: BTW This is not my Full design. This is just HTML

Comment: Ahah im looking back at this after 4 years and holy shit. I was 14 at this point and trying to create sites. Oh boy, cant believe ive been meddling with this for more than 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center an iframe you need to assign `display: block` to it.

For example:

```
iframe {
   display: block; // set display type
   margin: 0 auto; // align center
}
```

As we are not able to see your current stylesheet, it might be helpful to add your css to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You could put `iframe` in a `div` and center the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this css:

```
.video-wrapper {position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  padding-top: 25px; margin: auto;}
.video-wrapper iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.container {width: 100%; max-width: 300px; margin: auto;}
```

and structure your html like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V_qlumZ5K4I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your iframe will be responsive in width and height and will fit into whatever gap it is placed into (which should help you with your site being responsive) as well as centered on your page. Just alter the `max-width` on the `.container` to control the max width that you want the video to be.

Here is a fiddle to show you: https://jsfiddle.net/98e0ms1u/1/

Comment: Whenever I do that the height changes to around height="100", To say that its really thin.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add another container around that to control the width. See this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98e0ms1u/1/   I have also updated my answer and explained it a little more